# How to toggle between .cpp and .hpp that are not in the same directory?

Tags: emacs, lisp

Is there an Emacs function that toggles between `.cpp` and `.hpp` files that are not in the same directories?

I know there is [toggle-source.el](http://web.mit.edu/justom/Emacs/toggle-source.el), but it apparently does not handle the case where `.cpp` and `.hpp` are in different directories. But my directory structure is like this:

```
project1/src/foo.cpp
project1/include/foo.hpp
project2/src/bar.cpp
project2/include/bar.hpp
```

It shouldn't be hard to toggle between `src/foo.cpp` and `include/foo.hpp` but I don't speak Lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at *ff-find-other-file*, in *find-file.el*.  If the .h and .cpp files are in the same directory, this will just work, but you should be able to use it with different locations by modifying the value of *ff-search-directories*.

Comment: I tested this with the type of directory structure you mentioned, and _ff-find-other-file_ found the corresponding files successfully.  You should be able to just use that function without needing to customize anything.  If you have a more complicated directory structure, _cc-search-directories_ can be modified; _ff-search-directories_ gets its contents from _cc-search-directories_ by default.

Comment: It didn't work without customization for me; I had to modify `cc-search-directories`, but it works great!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the hint Brad! In case more people find this question, here is one way that worked for me (in emacs-23.2.1):

```
(setq cc-other-file-alist
      '(("\\.c"   (".h"))
       ("\\.cpp"   (".h"))
       ("\\.h"   (".c"".cpp"))))

(setq ff-search-directories
      '("." "../src" "../include"))

;;; Bind the toggle function to a global key
(global-set-key "\M-t" 'ff-find-other-file)
```